# Вывод количества ячеек в mysql после GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

После запроса в mysql

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY field1");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo'<tr><td>'.$test['field2'].'</td><td>Сюда кол-во ячеек</td></tr>';}
```

необходимо в таблицу вывести кол-во одинаковых ячеек, которое было до группировки `field1`. Не соображу, как?

Comment: `SELECT *, Count(*) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY field1`    ?

Comment: напишите пожалуйста поподробнее, а именно как применять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял вопрос, то

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT *, Count(*) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY field1");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo'<tr><td>'.$test['field2'].'</td><td>'.$test['cnt'].'</td></tr>';}
```

Учтите, что я не знаю `PHP`. Также может потребоваться заменить `*` на конкретно указанные поля.

Советую прочитать про агрегатные функции в `SQL`, без них применение `Group By` вообще малополезно

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что надо!